# trigger is working but no result

Tags: postgresql, function, triggers, pattern-matching

```
CREATE or replace FUNCTION billtesting() RETURNS trigger AS
$$
BEGIN
if (destination_number'^(?:[0-7] ?){6,14}[0-9]$' ~ digits and destination_number !~ '15487498')
then
insert into isp_cdr(destination_number,caller_id,duration,billsec)
values (destination_number,caller_id,duration,billsec);
UPDATE isp_cdr
SET nibble_total_billed = billsec * user_rate;  
end if;
RETURN NEW;
END
$$
LANGUAGE plpgsql;



CREATE TRIGGER bill_testing_update
BEFORE UPDATE 
ON isp_cdr
FOR EACH ROW
EXECUTE PROCEDURE billtesting();
```

This is the query for testing

```
    insert into isp_cdr(destination_number,caller_id,duration,billsec)
        values ('012687512123','123125641','43','35');
```

This is the sample lcr table information

```
digits       user_rate
1              0.02
23             0.07
652            0.12
1123           0.28
87521          0.15
123161         0.54
9641231        1.20
65491641       0.89

this is the sample isp_cdr table information
destination_number    caller_id        duration         billsec     nibble_total_billed

123561231              1315142             67             58         0
```

with this trigger procedure i want to match the digits with destination_number with and use the user_rate to do the calculation
user_rate  * billsec = nibble_total_billed

but after the insert the testing query the calculation does working it din't show any result at nibble_total_billed what i think is my pattern matching part has some mistake i need to match the digits with the destination_number.

Comment: (1) This does not look right: `destination_number'^(?:[0-7] ?){6,14}[0-9]$' ~ digits`. 
(2) You did not reference table `lcr` anywhere, how could digits and user_rate be included
(3) When writing a trigger function, reference the new/updated row using NEW and OLD, eg. NEW.destination_number
(4) Your trigger is for UPDATE yet your test query is INSERT
I think you need to read the [documentation](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/plpgsql-trigger.html#PLPGSQL-DML-TRIGGER) again.

Comment: Hi can u guide me on this im still new to this i not sure which part to change it  about the pattern matching for destination_number match to digits how can i do that ?

Comment: Don't `update` the table for which the trigger fired. Assign the value to the `new` record. See the examples in the manual: https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/plpgsql-trigger.html#PLPGSQL-TRIGGER-EXAMPLE  Also: `if (destination_number'^(?:[0-7] ?){6,14}[0-9]$' ~ digits...)` looks wrong. I'm surprised that even compiles And why are you inserting a new row in an `UPDATE` trigger? You also need to reference all columns through the `new` or `old` record.